# Update all elements of an array if value is greater than zero decrement by 1 MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I very beginner in MongoDB, I have collection called users

user 1:

```
{
  "_id": 1,
  "city_name": "Newyork",
  "device":[
    {
      "ime_number" : 1234343,
      "validity" : 40
    }
    ]
}
```

user 2:

```
{
  "_id": 2,
  "city_name": "London",
  "device":[
    {
      "ime_number" : 3434334,
      "validity" : 30
    }
    ]
}
```

I want to update all validity in collection is greater than zero validity decrement by 1

I tried this answer Not working

```
db.users.updateMany({"devices.validity": {$gt: 0}}, {$inc: {validity: -1}});
```

Value not updated in array

Answer (score 0):

As the `device` is an array,

Update with `arrayFilters` and `$[<identifier>]` filtered positional operator.

```
db.users.updateMany({},
{
  $inc: {
    "device.$[device].validity": -1
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "device.validity": {
        $gt: 0
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vpytWf6_f8E)